# How to integrate $\int_0^b x\cdot(a-x)^\frac{1}{7} dx$

Tags: integration

How to integrate 
$$\int_0^b x\cdot(a-x)^\frac{1}{7} dx$$
with $a,b,x>0$

Comment: u = a - x   : x = a - u : dx = - du : then expand it to a polynomial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution $u=a-x$ gives us

$$=-\int_a^{a-b}(a-u)u^{1/7}\ du=\int^a_{a-b}au^{1/7}-u^{8/7}\ du=\left.\frac78au^{8/7}-\frac7{15}u^{15/7}\right|_{a-b}^a$$